# Gwibber is not able to connect to facebook

Tags: 12.04, gwibber

I am running gwibber on 12.04 and I am unable to get facebook to connect to gwibber all I get after I login to facebook is Success and then nothing I have reported this as a bug I was wondering if there was a way to correct this issue. I have read the other posts on this and none of the answers I seen tried and none of them worked. I was hoping that I might get some fresh answers that might work. [image]

Comment: Hello @rstreeter78, have you already tried to do this: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-facebook-not-working-with-gwibber.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug. A fix should come soon.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672